# PHP/MYSQL How to Insert/Update Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a database using a form, but its not adding the item or updating. Deleting the item works but that's it. What am I doing wrong and how can I do to resolve this?

[image]
Thank You in advance your assistance is appreciated.

**INSERT ITEM PAGE**

```
  <?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['PART_DESC'])) {


             $PART_DESC = $row["PART_DESC"];
             $SERIAL_NUM = $row["SERIAL_NUM"];
             $RACK_NUM = $row["RACK_NUM"];
             $PART_TYPE_ID = $row["PART_TYPE_ID"];
             $PART_TYPE_DESC = $row["PART_TYPE_DESC"];
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT PART_ID FROM PART WHERE ='$PART_ID' LIMIT 1");
    $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="inventory.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO PART (PART_DESC, SERIAL_NUM, RACK_NUM, PART_TYPE_DESC, LOCATION) 
        VALUES('$PART_DESC','$SERIAL_NUM','$RACK_NUM','$PART_TYPE_ID','$PART_TYPE_DESC',now() )") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();

    exit();
}

?>

<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

**EDIT ITEM PAGE**

```
<?php 
// Gather this product's full information for inserting automatically into the edit form below on page
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT PART_ID, PART_DESC, SERIAL_NUM, RACK.RACK_NUM, PART.PART_TYPE_ID, PART_TYPE_DESC, LOCATION
FROM PART
INNER JOIN PART_TYPE ON PART.PART_TYPE_ID = PART_TYPE.PART_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN RACK ON RACK.RACK_NUM = PART.RACK_NUM
WHERE PART_ID='$targetID' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

             $id = $row["PART_ID"];
             $PART_DESC = $row["PART_DESC"];
             $SERIAL_NUM = $row["SERIAL_NUM"];
             $RACK_NUM = $row["RACK_NUM"];
             $PART_TYPE_ID = $row["PART_TYPE_ID"];
             $PART_TYPE_DESC = $row["PART_TYPE_DESC"];
             $LOCATION = $row["LOCATION"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry dude that crap dont exist.";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['PART_DESC'])) {

    $pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisID']);

             $PART_DESC = $row["PART_DESC"];
             $SERIAL_NUM = $row["SERIAL_NUM"];
             $RACK_NUM = $row["RACK_NUM"];
             $PART_TYPE_ID = $row["PART_TYPE_ID"];
             $PART_TYPE_DESC = $row["PART_TYPE_DESC"];
             $LOCATION = $row["LOCATION"];

    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE PART SET PART_DESC='$PART_DESC', SERIAL_NUM='$SERIAL_NUM', PART.PART_TYPE_DESC='$PART_TYPE_DESC', RACK.RACK_NUM='$RACK_NUM', LOCATION='$LOCATION' 
    INNER JOIN PART_TYPE ON PART.PART_TYPE_ID = PART_TYPE.PART_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN RACK ON RACK.RACK_NUM = PART.RACK_NUM WHERE PART.PART_ID='$pid'");
    header("location: inventory.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

?>

Comment: You should add the `or die(mysql_error());` for the update, and see why it is not updating. You should also static cast the ID from get to INT or escape it as well.

Comment: don't you want to do: `$PART_DESC = mysql_real_escape_string($row["PART_DESC"]);` or does that data come from inside your database?

Comment: I see you checking for `$_POST['PART_DESC']` in your insert page but I don't see you actually using it

Comment: Do i need it or can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

This code looks weird:

```
INSERT INTO PART 
  (PART_DESC, SERIAL_NUM, RACK_NUM, PART_TYPE_DESC, LOCATION) 
VALUES
('$PART_DESC','$SERIAL_NUM','$RACK_NUM','$PART_TYPE_ID','$PART_TYPE_DESC',now())"
```

The `parts` table only has fields:

```
 part_id
 , part_desc
 , serial_num
 , rack_num
 , part_type_id
```

So those are the only fields you can insert. The foreign keys do not magically spread the inserts across multiple tables you have to do that yourself.
The foreign keys **only** prevent you from inserting dangling data (FK's that do not link into anything) in your tables, that's IT.

**How you can still do what you want with one insert**
If you're hell bound on doing the insert in one go, *(which I recommend)* do the following:
Create a `blackhole` table that holds all the fields that you want to insert.
Create an `after insert trigger` on the blackhole table and do the insertion logic in that.
This will automatically put all your insertion logic in a single transaction, so even if you're using MyISAM tables you still have ACID safe transactions :-).

```
/*create the blackhole table, adjust field types to match your tables*/
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`bhpartsinsert` (
  `part_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `serial_num` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `part_type_desc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`part_type_desc`)
) ENGINE=BLACKHOLE DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_bhparts_insert_each AFTER INSERT 
  ON bhpartsinsert FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE mypart_type_id INTEGER;
  DECLARE myrack_num INTEGER;

  SELECT part_type_id INTO mypart_type_id FROM part_type 
    WHERE part_type_desc = new.part_type_desc LIMIT 1;
  IF mypart_type_id IS NULL THEN BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO part_type VALUES (null, new.part_type_desc);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO mypart_type_id;
  END; END IF;

  SELECT rack_num INTO myrack_num FROM rack 
    WHERE location = new.location LIMIT 1;
  IF myrack_num IS NULL THEN BEGIN
    INSERT INTO rack VALUES (null, new.location);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO myrack_num;
  END; END IF;

  INSERT INTO part VALUES 
    (null, new.part_desc, new.serial_num, myrack_num, mypart_type_id);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**How this works**
Whatever you insert into a blackhole table gets forgotten, **but** triggers do get fired.
So I've made a trigger that fires after every insert of every row.
The trigger makes sure there's a location in the rack and makes sure there's a part_type and then does the correct insert into the parts tables.
I'm assuming your primary key fields are autoincrementing integers. If you insert a `null` MySQL will create a unique PK for you.
**Only use `null` for this, `0` sometimes works and sometimes doesn't depending on your config, null always works**

*BTW, please don't use all caps for your field names, if you're used to SQL syntax where KEYWORDS are all caps it's makes your head hurt*

Comment: I can do more than one insert if it easier im new to this stuff and im trying to expand on a tutorial I found. How would you add the information to the database using a simple form?

Comment: Please don't ask a question in a comment, the comment I'd need to answer that is too big to be practical. I recommend asking that in a new question. Because that's really a different subject

Comment: Just gave you +1 as the OP doesn't seem to be bothered to either accept or at least give +1. Shame for this kind of comprehensive answer to not get any feedback by OP.